# Wine Installation problem after apt-get update

Tags: 13.10, wine, software-installation

Since a `sudo apt-get update`, wine is no longer recognized by Ubuntu (as if I removed the package).

I decided to clean it completely and tried to install Wine again without success.
OS : **Ubuntu 13.10 64 bits**

Output of `sudo apt-get install wine`

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                     wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
```

Output of : `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

.
I found many different potential solutions on AskUbuntu, but no one works :(

Thanks in advance

EDIT : output of `sudo apt-cache policy wine`

```
wine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1~saucy1
  Version table:
     1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1~saucy1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
     1.4.1-0ubuntu7 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Did you add a wine specific PPA? Maybe that PPA is broken or its packages were missing. What is the output if you try to run "apt-cache policy wine" or "apt-cache policy wine1.6"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I still have the same problem. I updated my question in order to display the output of apt-cache policy wine

Comment: @CamicriSystems : I have run apt-get update and Ubuntu suggested me to update many packages including Wine!
I really don't understand, but it solved my problem 2 days after..
'6 upgraded, 35 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
'

Comment: Maybe because your repositories are outdated, so your apt-get failed to get available package candidates for wine (especially when using PPA based repositories). So I suggest to "apt-get update" first before installing new package.